# Python: Replace First Word That Shows Up with Another Word

Tags: python, string, replace

I have seven fruits that you are allowed to use in a sentence and you are allowed to write with more then one and as many times as you want. They are `Watermelon`, `Pear`, `Peach`, `Orange`, `Apple`, `Banana` and `Grapes`. I want to report the sentence back and also replace the first fruit that comes out no matter if the word is shown multiple times and there is multiple fruits that are given in allowed list with Brussel Sprouts as seen below.

> In: Apple apple apple what is a watermelon have to do to get an apple?
>
> Out: Brussel sprouts apple apple what is a watermelon have to do to get an
>   apple?
>
> In: The apple likes orange
>
> Out: The brussel sprouts likes orange

Right now I'm messing with this code below, but this only works for one fruit, and I need to check all seven at the same time to see which one is first and to have it replaced.

```
print sentence.replace("apple", "brussel sprouts", 1)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: It's showing now what I should expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through `re.sub` . `(.*?)` at the first helps to capture all the characters just before to the first fruit. And the pattern `(?:Watermelon|Pear|Peach|Orange|Apple|Banana|Grapes)` matches the first fruit name. So by replacing the matched characters by the characters inside group index 1 will give you the desired output.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Apple apple apple what is a watermelon have to do to get an apple?"
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)^(.*?)\b(?:Watermelon|Pear|Peach|Orange|Apple|Banana|Grapes)\b', r'\1brussel sprouts', s)
'brussel sprouts apple apple what is a watermelon have to do to get an apple?'
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)^(.*?)\b(?:Watermelon|Pear|Peach|Orange|Apple|Banana|Grapes)\b', r'\1brussel sprouts', 'The apple likes orange')
'The brussel sprouts likes orange'
```

`(?i)` called case-insensitive modifier which forces the regex engine to do a case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate problems here; The first is [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)'ing the position of a fruit if it exists in the string. The second is `replace`'ing the one who was found first. Since I don't want to solve your homework problem for you, I'll simply show you a small example that should get you started in the right direction.

```
sentence = "Apple apple apple what is a watermelon have to do to get an apple?".lower() # We lowercase it so that "Apple" == "apple", etc.
index = sentence.find("apple")
print(index)
>>> 0
index = sentence.find("banana") # This is what happens when searching for fruit not in sentence
print(index)
>>> -1
```

Now that you know about `find`, you should be easily able to figure out how to combine a series of `find` and `replace` operations to get your desired output.